# How would I print the Alphabet In a spiral starting from the bottom left corner?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, spiral

If I wanted to print something like this in a matrix:

```
G F E
H I D
A B C
```

How would I do this?

The code I currently have goes like this:

```
A B C
H I D
G F E
```

I would like the spiral to start on the bottom left-hand corner of the matrix, and rotate to the left.

Here is my current code to do that with numbers:

```
 int n = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] spiral = new int[n][n];
        int value = 1;
        int minCol = 0;  
        int maxCol = n-1;      
        int minRow = 0;  
        int maxRow = n-1;
        while (value <= n*n)
        {
            for (int i = minCol; i <= maxCol; i++)
            {
                spiral[minRow][i] = value;
                value++;
            }
             
            for (int i = minRow+1; i <= maxRow; i++) 
            { 
                spiral[i][maxCol] = value; 
                value++; 
            } 
            for (int i = maxCol-1; i >= minCol; i--)
            {
                spiral[maxRow][i] = value;        
                value++;
            }
             
            for (int i = maxRow-1; i >= minRow+1; i--) 
            {
                spiral[i][minCol] = value;
                value++;
            }
            minCol++;      
            minRow++;
            maxCol--;
            maxRow--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < spiral.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spiral.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(spiral[i][j]+ "\t");
            }
             
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
       for (int i = 0; i < spiral.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spiral.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(spiral[i][j]+ "\t");
            }
             
            System.out.println();
        }
```

to

```
       for (int i = spiral.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < spiral.length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(spiral[i][j]+ "\t");
            }
             
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Note the first for loop. It prints the lines in reverse order